# Как создать счетчик для сайта?

Tags: javascript

Как создать счетчик времени идущий вперед а не назад на javascript ! Заранее спасибо !

Comment: Я один не понял о чем речь?
@алексей поляков, что за счетчик идущий вперед?

Comment: отредактировал )

Comment: http://www.webalerts.ru/
напимер как тут только чтобы отсчет шел вперед ! 
ТО есть создал блок с чем то и поставил скрипт ! и время пошло только Вперед в будущее в то чего еще не случилось ))))))))))))))))))

Comment: надо считать сколько времени прошло от некоего действия ?

Comment: Обычно это называют секундомером

Comment: Да ! чтобы считалось от начала создания записи например или блока !

Comment: вот вроде-бы хорошая библиотека для работы со временем http://momentjs.com

вам нужно почитать
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-language/
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Comment: чтобы не секунды от запуска страницы ) а от моего создания блока то есть создал и таймер врубился ! и идет сам по себе )) потом время пришло я его снес нафиг и все сообщение удалил )) вот так !

Comment: @алексей поляков, я вам показал пример как пользоваться библиотекой, как задавайте start как вам угодно, читайте доки. Не просите кодить за вас.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [библиотека](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html), которую использует http://www.webalerts.ru/.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/z7vt8/